# Model Created With Pytorch's *list, .children(), and nn.sequential Produces Different Output Tensors

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model, pytorch-lightning

I’m currently trying to use a pretrained DenseNet in my model. I’m following this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_densenet/, and it works well, with an input of [1,3,244,244], it returns a [1,1000] tensor, exactly as expected.
However, currently I’m using this code to load a pretrained Densenet into my model, and use it as a “feature extraction” model. This is the code in the init function

```
base_model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'densenet121', pretrained=True)

self.base_model = nn.Sequential(*list(base_model.children())[:-1])
```

And it is being used like this in the forward function

```
x = self.base_model(x)
```

This however, taking the same input, returns a tensor of the size: ([1, 1024, 7, 7]). I can not figure out what is not working, I think it is due to the fact that DenseNet connects all the layers together, but I do not know how to get it to work in the same method. Any tips in how to use pretrained DenseNet in my own model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `nn.Modules` have logic inside the `forward` definition, which means it won't be accessible by just converting the model to a sequential block. Most notably, you can generally find downsampling and/or flattening occurring between the CNN and the classifier layer(s) of the network. This is the for DenseNet.

If you look at Torchvision's forward implementation of DenseNet [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/densenet.py#L212) you will see:

```
def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    features = self.features(x)
    out = F.relu(features, inplace=True)
    out = F.adaptive_avg_pool2d(out, (1, 1))
    out = torch.flatten(out, 1)
    out = self.classifier(out)
    return out
```

You can see how the tensor outputted by the CNN `self.features` (shaped `(*, 1024, 7, 7)`) is processed through a ReLU, Adaptive average pool, and flatten before being fed to the classifier (the last layer).